# Codeigniter getuser() returns 0 after facebook dialog

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, nginx

You could say that this post is dublicate but I'm searching for nearly 2 days , couldn't figured out.

After moved to new server and installed new ssl, I'm having difficulties for facebook login in two different scenarios.

**First Scenario:**

User haven't logged in to facebook and facebook login redirects user to , facebook login. After user login, facebook redirects to redirect_url and getuser returns 0.

(User could login if return back to facebook login page on my website so getuser works when user already logged in to facebook).

**Second Scenario:**

User signs up, goes to permissions dialogue and when user gives permissions, again getuser returns 0 , so I was thinking to skip first scenario but this scenario is viral.

**I have tried this solutions :**

We are using nginx now, in previous server I did this updates and today I will tell you which conf we already added.

1- Base_facebook.php code needs to be updated for codeigniter and new php versions.

[Facebook PHP SDK: Fixing getUser() on PHP 5.4.x](https://www.webniraj.com/2012/12/19/facebook-php-sdk-fixing-getuser-on-php-5-4-x)

2- Nginx cookie sized changed, at the beginning even normal facebook login doesn't work.

3- I read something about nginx custom headers , we did these updates [nginx-php-fpm-and-custom-header](https://serverfault.com/questions/403728/nginx-php-fpm-and-custom-header)

[Nginx underscore headers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers)

4- CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false added to base_facebook, again another solution for other users.

I think after all these updates we missed a little something but I really can't see what is wrong? So I will be really happy if you could share your experience with me we could figure out what is wrong.

5-  parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_REQUEST); added before libraries included.

My example fb_login controller. I'm tank_auth_social with tank_auth

```
 function fblogin()
{

    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_REQUEST);
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('security');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth_social');
    $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
    $fb_id = $this->facebook->getUser();

    //inline_debug($fb_id);
    // To see if we have facebook id




    // User is found
    if( isset($fb_id) )
    {
        $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/'.$fb_id);

    }
```

My Conf:

PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4
Nginx, FPM PHP
My server is on digitalocean.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added sample code, I haven't added sample code because I think this problem is server side problem. Every was working 3 days ago.

Comment: Upgrade to using the new SDK.  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

Comment: I'm using Codeigniter and v4 uses vendor type, I have to change everything if I want to use v4. Last resort I will do it.

My main problem is to workout getuser() after facebook authorize.

Comment: Is there any option to change PHP version in your website control panel? I had similar issue when I changed to 5.4 it worked. Please try that also.

Comment: Thanks Nish, I think last solution will be this, I tested Facebook Sdk 4, same problem in 2 scenarios. It's really pity that we have to downgrade php 5.4

Comment: I'm testing with PHP 5.4 , still no luck, I'm really curious about php fpm and nginx is doing so security tricks there. Added try&catch if there is user send do getlogin again but it causes infinity loop.

Comment: I realized that after ssl installed after 19th of this month, my facebook app doesn't show any active user, is it normal? Also testing with normal php sdk test on outside of framework it always give, oauth exception... I think I'm gonna kill myself !!!